# SQL Server OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Temp\Test.xml', SINGLE_CLOB) Returns Garbled Leading Characters

Tags: sql-server, openrowset

When writing the contents of an xml file to a `nvarchar(MAX)` column using `OPENROWSET` I end up with garbled leading characters.

Even when doing a select without the insert the result is the same.

```
SELECT Xml.BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Temp\Test.xml', SINGLE_CLOB) Xml
```

Result:

[image]

I have experimented with the various `CODEPAGE` options but get the same result.

```
SELECT Xml.BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Temp\Test.xml', CODEPAGE='RAW', SINGLE_CLOB) Xml
```

In notepad the file looks fine.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to change the encoding of the xml file from UTF-8 to Unicode and then use SINGLE_NCLOB instead of SINGLE_CLOB.

```
SELECT Xml.BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Temp\Test2.xml', SINGLE_NCLOB) Xml
```

[image]

Comment: SQL Server before the 2016 version does not really support UTF-8

Comment: From Microsoft documentation: `Important
We recommend that you import XML data only using the SINGLE_BLOB option, rather than SINGLE_CLOB and SINGLE_NCLOB, because only SINGLE_BLOB supports all Windows encoding conversions.`

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql